# Creating Column in R Containing the top n highest row

Tags: r, dataframe

My data set looks like this:

```
    group <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
    item1.sep <- sample(1:10,7)
    item2.sep <- sample(1:10,7)
    item3.sep<- sample(1:10,7)
    item4.sep<- sample(1:10,7)
    item5.sep<- sample(1:10,7)
    item1.oct<- sample(1:10,7)
    item2.oct <- sample(1:10,7)
    item3.oct<- sample(1:10,7)
    item4.oct<- sample(1:10,7)
    item5.oct<- sample(1:10,7)

df <- data.frame(group,item1.sep,item2.sep,item3.sep,item4.sep,item5.sep,
                 item1.oct,item2.oct,item3.oct,item4.oct,item5.oct)


    group   item1.sep   item2.sep....   item5.oct
       1       9           9             4  
       2       4           4             7  
       3       7           7             2  
       4       3           8             5  
       5       8           3             1  
       6       6          10             8  
       7      10           2             6
```

And I want to create 2 new columns containing the top 2 item as character for each month. Maybe a combination of max and merge would help in this one

```
          Top2_Sept   Top2_Oct             group....    item5.oct
 item3.sep,item2.sep  item5.Oct,item2.Oct      1         9  
 item4.sep,item1.sep       .                   2         4          
 item2.sep,item5.sep       .                   .         .
 item4.sep,item2.sep       .                   .         .
 item1.sep,item3.sep       .                   .         .
 item2.sep,item5.sep       .                   .         .
 item4.sep,item1.sep       .                   .
```

Comment: sorry about that, it seems that I can only accept one but yours is also correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a data.table solution.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[,Top2_Sept:=paste(names(.SD)[order(unlist(.SD),decreasing=TRUE)[1:2]],collapse=","),
          .SDcols=2:6,by=group]
DT[,Top2_Oct:=paste(names(.SD)[order(unlist(.SD),decreasing=TRUE)[1:2]],collapse=","),
          .SDcols=7:11,by=group]
DT[,list(group,Top2_Sept,Top2_Oct)]
#    group           Top2_Sept            Top2_Oct
# 1:     1 item5.sep,item3.sep item2.oct,item1.oct
# 2:     2 item2.sep,item4.sep item1.oct,item5.oct
# 3:     3 item5.sep,item3.sep item3.oct,item2.oct
# 4:     4 item4.sep,item1.sep item5.oct,item1.oct
# 5:     5 item2.sep,item4.sep item4.oct,item5.oct
# 6:     6 item1.sep,item2.sep item1.oct,item2.oct
# 7:     7 item1.sep,item2.sep item1.oct,item2.oct
```

Your example is not quite reproducible because you did not `set.seed(...)` prior to creating the random samples. The result above will reproduce if you `set.seed(1)` at the beginning.

Also, there is an ambiguity in your rules. Suppose `item1.sep:item5.sep` for a given row is `(8,7,7,6,5)`. Then the top item is in the first col, but the second item could be in the second or third column. You present no rule to resolve that.

Comment: Agree to the importance of using `st.seed(...)` to make reproducible examples!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
lst1 <- split(colnames(df)[-1],sub(".*\\.", '',colnames(df)[-1]))
df[paste("Top2", c("Oct", "Sept"), sep="_")] <-  lapply(lst1, function(x) {
            nm1 <- colnames(df[x])
           apply(df[x], 1, function(.x) 
           toString(nm1[order(.x, decreasing=TRUE)[1:2]]))})
```

Or

```
lst1 <- lapply(month.abb[9:10], function(x)
         df[grep(x, colnames(df), ignore.case=TRUE)])
nm1 <- lapply(lst1, colnames)
f1 <- function(x,y) apply(x, 1, function(.x)
          toString(y[order(.x, decreasing=TRUE)[1:2]]))

 df[paste('Top2', month.abb[9:10], sep="_")] <- Map(f1, lst1, nm1)
```